# Numpy: Co-ordinate Array to Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

Suppose I have a set of co-ordinate numpy arrays over `batches` and `channels`.

Each array has:

- a `N` entries of x-y-z coordinates ranging between 0 and `lim` from index `0:2`
- a value on the fourth index associated with the co-ordinate on index `3`.

How do I broadcast this coordinate array to a 'graph' array, `graph`, such that each unique coordinate contained in `coords` is expressed as the sum of all the co-ordinates at that index?

i.e. :

```
coords = np.random.randint(0,lim,(batches, channels,N, 4))
graph = foo(coords)
graph.shape = (batches, channels, lim, lim, lim)
```

In a simple case, one would do the following:

```
def foo(coords):
    graph = np.zeros(batches, channels, lim, lim, lim)
    for b_i in range(batches):
        for c_i in range(channels):
            for n_i in range(N):
                elem = coords[b_i, c_i, n_i]
                if elem[3] > 0:
                   graph[b_i, c_i, elem[0], elem[1], elem[2]]+=elem[3]
    return graph
```

However, I am looking for a solution involving broadcasting so I can port the technique to PyTorch, where the broadcasting is mandatory for speed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized solution to your loop:

```
mask = np.argwhere(coords[:,:,:,3]>0)
graph = np.zeros((batches, channels, lim, lim, lim))
idx = coords[tuple(mask.T)]
graph[tuple(np.hstack((mask[:,0:2], idx[:,:3])).T)] += idx[:,3]
```